# R: why cannot find variables

Tags: r

I am new to R and I think I missed something fundamentally. Why can't R find the variable which I supplied and didn't change? In another words, I cannot use my variable at all.

```
> dat = read_sas("e:/Users/mhollifi/Desktop/cps/ex1_1/jan00pub.sas7bdat", "e:/Users/mhollifi/Desktop/cps/ex1_1/formats.sas7bcat")
> summary(PENATVTY)
Error in summary(PENATVTY) : object 'PENATVTY' not found
> names(dat)
[1] "PEEDUCA"     "PENATVTY"    "cntryorigin"
> print(dat)
# A tibble: 96,589 x 3
   PEEDUCA PENATVTY cntryorigin
     <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>
 1    34.0     57.0           0
 2    40.0     57.0           0
 3    37.0     57.0           0
 4    37.0     57.0           0
 5    40.0     57.0           0
 6    39.0     57.0           0
 7    39.0     57.0           0
 8    39.0     57.0           0
 9    39.0     57.0           0
10    43.0     57.0           0
# ... with 96,579 more rows
> exists("PENATVTY")
[1] FALSE
> summary(PENATVTY)
Error in summary(PENATVTY) : object 'PENATVTY' not found
>   lapply(PENATVTY, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
Error in lapply(PENATVTY, mean, na.rm = TRUE) : 
  object 'PENATVTY' not found
```

Comment: try `dat$PENATVTY`

Comment: Welcome to R. `PENATVTY` appears to be a *column within `dat`*, not its own variable.

Comment: ...or `dat[["PENATVTY"]]` or `dat[[2]]` or `dat[,2]` or `dat[,"PENATVTY"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PENATVTY` isn't an object in your R session. `dat` is and has a column named `PENATVTY`.

All of `dat$PENATVTY` , `dat[[PENATVTY]]` and `dat[,"PENATVTY"]` will return what you're looking for. If you want to use `summary`, you can do:

```
PENATVTY <- dat$PENATVTY #creates a vector named PENATVTY containing the column from dat
summary(PENATVTY)
```

You can also manipulate `dat$PENATVTY` directly:

```
summary(dat$PENATVTY)
```

If you want the mean of `PENATVTY`, you don't need `lapply`

```
mean(dat$PENATVTY,na.rm=TRUE)
```

will give the mean.